# Try get multiple links from webpage in Selenium using Java and PhantomJS

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

I have an problem using Java, Selenium and PhantomJS. I would like to get multiple buttonlinks from a webpage (using an css selector) but it doesn't work.

```
    link = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.a:nth-child("+ elementCounter +") > div:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1)")).getAttribute("href");

    elementCounter++;
System.out.println("counters: "+elementCounter + link);
```

the elementCounter that I use does count +1 but the counter in the css selector doesn't work(it keeps getting the same buttonlink).
The code does stand in an while loop but still it doesn't work.

Here below the html structure:

```
<div class="a">
<a href="test.php?id=393">hello world</a>
</div>
<div class="b">
<a href="test.php?id=394">hello world</a>
</div>
<div class="c">
<a href="test.php?id=395">hello world</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the structure of the page? The HTML markup?

Comment: I see no loop in your code, so there can't be any counting. Please [edit] your question to include a larger portion of your code.

Comment: Also note that *findElement* returns the first element that matches. Have you tried using *findElement**s***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would switch to XPath, if possible. If there are any other requirements on child-parent relationships they are quite easy to add.

This gets all links in the page that are under a `<div>` element:

```
List<WebElement> anchorElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div/a"));
System.out.println(anchorElements.size() + " links found");
for (WebElement a : anchorElements) {
    System.out.println("Link: " + a.getText() + " links to " + a.getAttribute("href"));
}
```

Or in Java 8

```
List<WebElement> anchorElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div/a"));
System.out.println(anchorElements.size() + " links found");
anchorElements.stream().forEach(a -> System.out.println("Link: " + a.getText() + " links to " + a.getAttribute("href"));
```

Comment: First of all thanks for helping me. The code does work but now it keeps on looping true my code so I keep on getting links. I have an fail counter but that doesn't work.

Comment: @rahul This code will print all links in the page. Do you wish to stop after a  certain count?

Comment: no  I would like to make an selection on the list and covert it to a string